# How can I share settings between two WPF apps?

Tags: c#, wpf, settings

I have a pair of apps. One is a game for young kids. The other is a tool for use by the parents. I separate the apps in this way to keep the UI as simple as possible for the kids.

One part of the parent app is to control specific settings of the kids' app. I've just been using Settings.settings for most of my settings up to now, but can't see a simple way for the parent app to access and change the settings in the kids' app (apart from a rather kludgy back-door using XML).

Is there a way, or alternatively, is there another place I should consider keeping my shared settings?

I like the ease of two-way binding for managing settings via a dialog, but could survive without that if necessary.

FWIW: Both apps do use a common DLL where a lot of common code resides. Maybe there's a way of leveraging that?

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use a database that is accessible to both apps?

Comment: @ThemIxy: It's such a small number of settings, and there's no other need for a database in the app, so I feel that would be overkill.

Comment: If the apps are going to be installed on differentt devices, than you will have to consider using a DB or a web service.

Comment: @TheMixy: Just desktop, so no worries there.

Comment: Looks like there may be some reasonable way using ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration, but having trouble getting to the setting. It doesn't show up there. :/

Comment: If it's the same computer just make settings in the app available to the 'parent user' only / or put a json file in a shared folder. Access it read/write from parent app and access it read only from child app

Comment: @TheMixy: Not about users. It's two different apps. The parent app needs to be able to set values that are then read by the kids' app. Not sure what you mean by "just make the settings in the app available" - i.e that's the question.

Comment: Put a json file in a shared folder. Write settings to it. Access it read/write from parent app and access it read only from child app

Answer (score 0):

You can save the settings to a file into a common folder like the below (eg C:\ProgramData\yourfolder)

```
String DataPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + "\\yourfolder";
```

and access the settings file from both applications. No need of a database and easy of use.

The settings file can be a simple json or whatever you feel comfortable.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I went with having a class that contains the shared settings. Here's the main part of it:

```
public class AppConfig
{
    public int SaveSize = 1000;
    //... other shared settings here

    static private bool ready = false;
    static private AppConfig instance;
    static public AppConfig Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (!ready)
            {
                ReadFromFile();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }

    static private readonly string filename = Common.AppDataFileName("config.xml");

    static private void ReadFromFile()
    {
        ready = true;

        if (!File.Exists(filename))
        {
            instance = new AppConfig();
            return;
        }

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AppConfig));
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
        {
            instance = (AppConfig)serializer.Deserialize(fs);
        }
    }

    static public void Save()
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AppConfig));
        using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, Instance);
        }
    }
}
```

Because you have to have an instance for serialization, I instantiate that on-demand and then refer to it as needed. E.g.:

```
int size = AppConfig.Instance.SaveSize;
```

Don't know if this is the best way, but it works for my needs for now. If it is a bad way to do this, don't be shy to comment below. I'm here to learn!